# RecyclerView expand/collapse

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout, expandablerecyclerview

1. I want to expand/collapse content like below image when I click on a item of RecyclerView.
2. It's the same effect of the new Android recent calls history list. The options "CALL" and "DETAILS" or "SEND MESSAGE" are visible only when an item is selected.
3. **Image:**
   [Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUVve.jpg)
4. And here is My **RecyclerViewAdapter** Class, thanks you so much:

   public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
       Context mContext;
       List mData;

   ```
   public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Contact> mData) {
       this.mContext = mContext;
       this.mData = mData;
   }

   @NonNull
   @Override
   public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
       View v;
       v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_contact, viewGroup, false);
       MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

       return viewHolder;
   }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
       myViewHolder.tvName.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
       myViewHolder.tvFname.setText(mData.get(position).getFname());
       myViewHolder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());
   }

   @Override
   public int getItemCount() {
       return mData.size();
   }

   public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       private TextView tvName;
       private TextView tvFname;
       private ImageView img;

       public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

           super(itemView);
           tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
           tvFname = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFname);
           img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_contact);
       }
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Another way is to put the logic of expand/collapse in your ViewHolder class

Comment: one way would be to add another field to the data used by the adapter and based on that, hide / show the expanded view

Comment: @@ Can you give me some code to more info

Comment: You can use expandable layout from this library into your item.xml to implement what you want https://github.com/cachapa/ExpandableLayout